# Generate multiple pages using getServerSideProps with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My demo API will return

```
[
  {
    title: "First article",
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    title: "Second article",
    id: "2"
  }
]
```

I want to create a page for each.

The component will be placed in `pages/articles/[id].js`

My component will look like this

```
function Article(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return <div>...</div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch("https://.../articles");
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { data }
  }
}
```

This will create one single page, but with the whole feed as props.
How do I create a page for each object?

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering
This only tells me how to create unique page to the single article

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const articleId = context.query.id;
  const res = await fetch("https://.../articles");
  const articles = await res.json();

  const [article] = articles.filter((article) => article.id === articleId);

  return {
    props: { article },
  };
}
```